# SQL: Count each record, starting with the oldest to newest appointment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below in which I need to count each appointment and grouping by the ID and Type then order by the oldest appointment and giving it a number and count up.

I am using MS SQL sever management studio.

```
Select ID, Date, Type
From Appointment
Where Type='Post-op'
```

Before

```
ID  | Date          | Type
123 | 2013-01-01    | Post-op
123 | 2013-01-21    | Post-op
123 | 2013-02-28    | Post-op
123 | 2013-05-16    | Post-op
124 | 2013-01-21    | Post-op
124 | 2013-02-12    | Post-op
```

After

```
ID  | Date          | Type      | Count
123 | 2013-01-01    | Post-op   | 1
123 | 2013-01-21    | Post-op   | 2
123 | 2013-02-28    | Post-op   | 3
123 | 2013-05-16    | Post-op   | 4
124 | 2013-01-21    | Post-op   | 1
124 | 2013-02-12    | Post-op   | 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a windowed function in your SELECT

```
SELECT id
      ,[date]
      ,type
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [date] ) AS seq
FROM  Appointment
WHERE Type = 'Post-op'
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3a4f/1

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are after [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with TempData as (Select ID  ,Date,Type DataCount =ROW_NUMBER()
                    over(PARTITION By Id Order By Date)
                    From Appointment
                    Where Type='Post-op')

Select * from TempData
```